# Status of structured streaming query in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am following the book Spark - Definitive Guide and I was writing basic program that streams the data . The books says that I should use awaitTermination() method to process the query correctly. When I run the below code , it runs indefinitely until I press Ctrl+C and it ends with exception. My question is how can I monitor the status of my streaming query and as soon as  my streaming completes , my program should exit after showing the output. Like in the example code below , as soon as it reads all the files and writes the file on the console , it should have ended but it didn't . I also tried inserting activityQuery.stop() but that also didn't work. How can I achieve the same . Any help be appreciated.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from time import sleep


conf = SparkConf()
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).appName('testapp').getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 2)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference", "true")
static = spark.read.format("json").load("/home/scom/.test/spark/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/activity-data/")
dataSchema = static.schema
streaming = spark.readStream.schema(dataSchema).option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).json("/home/scom/.test/spark/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/activity-data/")
activityCounts = streaming.groupBy("gt").count()
activityQuery = activityCounts.writeStream.queryName("activity_counts").format("console").outputMode("complete").start()
activityQuery.awaitTermination()
for x in range(5):
  spark.sql("select * from activity_counts").show()
  sleep(1)
```

Comment: not sure why do you need streaming job for this? you can read it as static dataset and show the output or write to somewhere. if you still want to use streaming way of loading the dataset, then you can use Trigger.Once option

Comment: the purpose of awaitTermination() is to make sure the application is continuously running, until it stopped manually or by some exception.

Comment: @Shankar one more thing ..when  I use format("console") , I get the output but when I use the format("memory") and try to query the table activity_counts ..nothing shows up. Any idea why this is happening or do i miss something. The code above in the question is same ..just I change format to memory